# Android/Google Advertising ID - Is this method of gaining user consent to store permitted?

Tags: android, google-advertising-id

I'd like to store the Google Advertising IDs from users of an Android app I have, so that at a later date I am able to work with an ad network to target our users based on the information I have about them (for re-engagement, etc).

The Google guidelines around this state:

"**Association with personally identifiable information or other identifiers.**
 The advertising identifier must not be connected to personally identifiable
 information or associated with any persistent device identifier 
 (for example: SSAID, MAC address, IMEI, etc.) without the explicit consent of the user."

How can I gain consent of the user for this? My first thought was a tick box to say 'We have updated our privacy policy, please accept the updated terms to continue', however a 3rd party advertising agency has advised that I can simply update the terms on the Play Store, and that continued use would count as 'explicit consent'. I am concerned about this however, as people using auto-update will presumably never read the text on the Play Store, and this may contravene the guidelines.

Has anyone had any experience with this? This isn't an app I can really afford to get yanked from the Store, so I'd really like to be sure of the rules, rather than risk it and hope no-one notices (if indeed it is incorrect).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a popupbox with the updated Terms of Service or a link pointing to them with two options: `Accept` and `Quit`. This way you have shown them the updated ToS and didn't update them behind their backs.